# Want image and text to change onmouseover on section

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to make HTML code on my wordpress site to display text and change the picture I hover my mouse over when I go over a certain section.

I can see the section hyperlinked but I cannot get the picture changed or the text to display, what is wrong with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function writeText(txt)
{
document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML=txt;
}
// ]]></script>
<img alt="DogAnatomy" src="http://www.knowyourcompanion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/DogAnatomy-1024x791.png" usemap="#planetmap" width="1024" height="791" />

<map name="planetmap">

<area onmouseover="this.src='http://www.knowyourcompanion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/DogAnatomyEars.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.knowyourcompanion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/DogAnatomy-1024x791.png'" alt="Sun" coords="163,90,  163,82,  159, 67,  155,55,  152, 42,  152,27,  155 23, 160,25,  165,32, 169,38,  173,46,  171,34,  171,24,  175, 16,  180,15,  189,20,  195,29,  199,42,  203,53,  212,66,  219, 75,  227,88,  234,98,  237,106,  237,112,  228,114,  217,115,  205,113,  187,109,  176,103" shape="poly" href="sun.htm" target="_blank"  />

<area onmouseover="writeText('The dog's ears are fantastic/! They can hear over eighteen times the distance we can/!')" alt="Sun" coords="163,90,  163,82,  159, 67,  155,55,  152, 42,  152,27,  155 23, 160,25,  165,32, 169,38,  173,46,  171,34,  171,24,  175, 16,  180,15,  189,20,  195,29,  199,42,  203,53,  212,66,  219, 75,  227,88,  234,98,  237,106,  237,112,  228,114,  217,115,  205,113,  187,109,  176,103" shape="poly" href="sun.htm" target="_blank"  />
```

ps. this is just a section of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to change the SRC attribute from the Area element.

Change this

```
<area onmouseover="this.src=...." onmouseout="this.src=..." ...>
```

For this

```
<area onmouseover="document.getElementById('dogImage').src=..." onmouseout="document.getElementById('dogImage')=..." ...>
```

And in your dog img put an ID, in this case you can use dogImage

```
<img id="dogImage" ...>
```

It's unnecesary to use two area in your code, you can just simple add the call to the writeText function after changing the src attribute.

And check out the call for the writeText function, you have single quote unescaped. Change it by this

```
 writeText('The dog\'s ears...');
```

And just a tip: do not use nested javascript code with the HTML. Try to add a event listener for each element.

Here's is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/D6sC5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `this` when called inside the `onmouseover` event of the `<area>` tag, is referring to the `<area>` tag and so will be changing the `src` attribute of the `<area>` tag and not the `<img>` tag like your intending.
Add an ID to the img:

```
<img id="dog" alt="DogAnatomy" src="http://www.knowyourcompanion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/DogAnatomy-1024x791.png" usemap="#planetmap" width="1024" height="791" />
```

Then reference that in the onmouseover:

```
<area onmouseover="document.getElementById('dog').src='http://www.knowyourcompanion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/DogAnatomyEars.png'">
```

You will also probably want to escape your apostrophes in the `writeText` function:
`\'`